# No 'Add google account' option

Tags: google-account, greenify

So  I have a rooted S3 Mini VE (i8200) with stock custom rom (samsung apps and gapps but with custom theme). I just installed it recently. I could add my google account successfully. I was playing with greenify cut-off (com.marvel.ppgadget WakeupThing), the ap just CTD. Np, i restarted it and de-greenified ppgadget. Later on, i just saw that Google App asked me to add a google account. So I went to Settings > Account and noticed that there were no google account option.

I tried disable xposed, set Greenify to non-root, removing xposed, wiping cache and dalvik cache, reflashing rom. Didn't changed anything. BTW all gaaps are installed.